# How to call public method of ViewChild in Angular 10

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call a public method on a child component from my parent component but I'm getting the error

> core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: this.foo.bar is not a function

which I understand th is is because even though my ViewChild is of type `ChildComponent` it's not *actually* a `ChildComponent`, it's just the same shape as a `ChildComponent` but ultimately is just a plain old JS object.

So how do I call a public method on a child component?

My code looks like:

parent.html

```
<app-child-component #childComponent></app-child-component>
```

parent.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
{
    @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent:ChildComponent;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.childComponent.foo(); // ERROR TypeError: this.childComponent.foo is not a function
    }
}
```

childComponent.ts

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
{
    public foo(): void
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check what is the instance of the `childComponent` in the parent? by console.log

Comment: Try AfterViewInit instead of OnInit.

Comment: you can also query by class `@ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working the problem through and getting a different error that [lead me to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333739/angular2-rc6-component-is-not-a-known-element/40254083) I've realised that the module where the child component is defined had the component in it's `declarations` but not in it's `exports`.

What I had:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ]
})
export class ChildModule {
}
```

What I needed:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ChildComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ChildComponent
    ]
})
export class ChildModule {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`foo()` cannot be called because the `childComponent` object has not been instantiated by the time the `OnInit` lifecycle hook fires.

From the Angular lifecycle hooks [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks):

| Hook method | Purpose | Timing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ngOnInit() | Initialize the directive or component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive or component's input properties. | Called once, after the first ngOnChanges(). |

Instead you should place the call to `childComponent.foo()` in the `AfterViewInit` callback.

| Hook method | Purpose | Timing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ngAfterViewInit() | Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views, or the view that contains the directive. | Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked(). |

Your solution would then be:

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
{
    @ViewChild('childComponent') childComponent: ChildComponent;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.childComponent.foo(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. If I call the method in ngAfterViewInit I get `ERROR TypeError: this.childComponent.foo is not a function`. and if I `console.log(this.childComponent)` I get `ElementRef {nativeElement: app-child-component.ng-tns-c519-21}`.  

It's strange, I've found this StackBlitz which is exactly what I'm doing https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-call-child-componentss-method-from-the-parent-com-eremif?file=src/app/app.component.ts, same use of `ViewChild` same `#foo` on the element, as  you can see in the StackBlitz the `console.log` shows `ChildComponent` and not `ElementRef.