# Angular component is not recognizable by Angular

Tags: angular

My `todos.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todos',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './todos.component.html',
  styleUrl: './todos.component.css'
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(){

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      
  }

}
```

My `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Todos List: Make Yourself Remind';
}
```

My `app.component.html` file:

```
<div>
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam doloribus omnis aspernatur?</p>
  <app-todos></app-todos>
</div>
```

Error getting error after doing `ng serve`:

```
X [ERROR] NG8001: 'app-todos' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-todos' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-todos' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:4:2:
      4 │   <app-todos></app-todos>
        ╵   ~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Application bundle generation failed. [6.155 seconds]
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
```

Dont know why this is happening!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 RC6: '<component> is not a known element'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333739/angular2-rc6-component-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: You forgot to import the todo component

Comment: @JSONDerulo Where should I import it?? inside app.component.ts??

Comment: Seriously? Two people answered your simple question in comments, which is asked 100 times here and you create an answer yourself the same which you read in link provided to you?

Answer (score 1):

Two changes are done to make it right:

1. Added `import { TodosComponent } from './MyComponents/todos/todos.component';` inside `app.component.ts`.
2. Added `TodosComponent` inside imports for `app.component.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, you need import your `TodosComponent` in the `app.component.ts` file and add it to the `imports` section. You can do as the code below depending on how your files are organized.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { TodosComponent } from './todos/todos.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, TodosComponent, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Todos List: Make Yourself Remind';
}
```

After that, you can call `<app-todos></app-todos>` as you want in your html code.